# Rendering texture as pure white / filled with color with SDL2

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl2, blending, alpha-blending

I added a glow or shine effect to make character flash with one color for a short period of time, it looks like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiMxKvZyMpU).
The code in draw function:

```
auto spr = m_currentAnimation->getSprite();
bool shining = m_shineLockedTimer.isActive() || m_shineAlphaTimer.isActive();

renderer_.renderTexture(spr, texPos.x + xoffset, texPos.y, camera_, flip);
if (shining)
    {
        float alpha = 1 - m_shineAlphaTimer.getProgressNormalized();

        auto pw = renderer_.createTexture(m_currentAnimation->getSize());
        renderer_.setRenderTarget(pw);
        renderer_.fillRenderer({255, 255, 255, 0});

        auto blendmode = SDL_ComposeCustomBlendMode(SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE, SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE, SDL_BLENDOPERATION_MAXIMUM, SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ONE, SDL_BLENDFACTOR_ZERO, SDL_BLENDOPERATION_ADD);
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(spr, blendmode);
        renderer_.renderTexture(spr, 0, 0);
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(spr, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(pw, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        SDL_SetTextureColorMod(pw, m_colorShine.r, m_colorShine.g, m_colorShine.b);
        SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(pw, alpha * m_colorShine.a);
            
        renderer_.setRenderTarget(nullptr);
        renderer_.renderTexture(pw, texPos.x + xoffset, texPos.y, camera_, flip);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(pw);
    }
```

On each frame during the flash effect, I create a new texture of the same size as the character's current sprite (which can change during the effect), fill it with white, create a blendmode that basically copies the alpha channel, render the sprite to this texture to get its pure white copy and render this white version with proper colormod and alphamod to the renderer. [Here's full .cpp file with this draw function](https://github.com/SavedowW/SomeSmallFG/blob/main/src/Character.cpp). I have 2 problems with this code:

1. It seems to be overly complex for a code that runs on each frame, since it recreates and destroyes texture and does a lot of rendering. One way to optimize it I've thought of is to create pure white versions of the textures along with the animations and use them, but this will double memory consumption by textures. Is it a good solution or are there better ones?
2. It causes [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EijZVulEdvQ) artifact when the effect is applied to both players. It specifically happens with the first renderer character, even if the rendering order changes during the animations. The effect remains on lower framerate. The character use the same SDL_Textures, but my code returns blend mode and render target to normal and the artifact remains even if the characters use different sprites and does not depend on alpha value. For some reason, it has a clear vertical border at some points of the screen, but only for the player with artifact. What could be the reason for it?

UPD. It seems that the reason for this bug was that I destroyed texture before `SDL_RenderPresent` call